# How to replace a line in a input file using sed/awk/perl

Tags: linux, sed, awk, perl

I am trying to replace a path in an input file.

```
    #include "../../../Plumed.h"         #### this is old patch in input 

    #include "/usr/local/include/Plumed.h  #### this should be the new path
```

After seeing to previously answered question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245144/replace-whole-line-containing-a-string-using-sed).

I tried this.

```
    sed -i '/../../../Plumed.h/c\/usr/local/include/Plumed.h' ../dist0.xvg


    perl -i -pe 's/../../../Plumed.h/usr/local/include/Plumed.h/g' ../dist0.xvg
```

I believe sed/perl is getting confused but I am not sure how to overcome this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What previously answered question? Please be more specific.

Comment: mentioned sir !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `/` as delimeter with `sed`, a solution could be:

```
sed -i 's/..\/..\/..\/Plumed.h/\/usr\/local\/include\/Plumed.h/g' file
```

or, you can use a different delimeter than `/`, for example `:`:

```
sed -i 's:../../../Plumed.h:/usr/local/include/Plumed.h:g' file
```

Another way with `awk`:

```
awk '{ gsub("../../../Plumed.h","/usr/local/include/Plumed.h"); print $0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

### **tl,dr:**

Use:

```
sed -i 's:"\.\./\.\./\.\./Plumed\.h":"/usr/local/include/Plumed.h":g' ../dist0.xvg
```

---

A few comments on your attempted Sed command:

> ```
> sed -i '/../../../Plumed.h/c\/usr/local/include/Plumed.h' ../dist0.xvg
> ```

- `-i` is not portable, so it appears you are using GNU Sed.

  BSD Sed has a `-i` switch as well, but the backup extension is a required argument, so to modify a file without saving a backup in BSD Sed requires `-i ''`.

  Other versions of Sed may have no `-i` switch at all.
- The regex here, `/../../../Plumed.h/`, contains multiple copies of the regex delimiter.

  The usual solution to this is to escape the delimiter:

  ```
  /..\/..\/..\/Plumed.h/
  ```

  However, there is a little-known fact about Sed, that you can use *any* character for the regex delimiter (not just in the `s` command) if you backslash-escape the first instance.  (Well, almost any—backslash or newline not allowed.)

  To quote the [POSIX specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02) directly:

  > In a context address, the construction "`\cBREc`", where *c* is any character other than `<backslash>` or `<newline>`, shall be identical to "`/BRE/`". If the character designated by *c* appears following a `<backslash>`, then it shall be considered to be that literal character, which shall not terminate the BRE. For example, in the context address "`\xabc\xdefx`", the second *x* stands for itself, so that the BRE is "`abcxdef`".

  So to avoid the "leaning toothpicks syndrome," note that the following two regexes are equivalent:

  ```
  /..\/..\/..\/Plumed.h/
  \:../../../Plumed.h:
  ```

  Note that I said "equivalent," *not* correct.  This brings me to my next point, missed in every other answer:
- **A period (`.`) in a regex stands for *any character*.**

  If you want to match only a literal period, you can either escape your period with a backslash, or stick it into a character class as in `[.]`.

  Thus to match only literal periods, the regex should actually be more like:

  ```
  \:\.\./\.\./\.\./Plumed\.h:
  ```

  So much for avoiding leaning toothpicks.

  You can also use the arguably more readable form:

  ```
  \:[.][.]/[.][.]/[.][.]/Plumed[.]h:
  ```
- The `c` command changes the *entire line*, not just the portion of the line matched by the regex.

  Use the `s` command to only change a portion of a line.

  Notably, with the `s` command, you don't have to escape your first regex delimiter (even for an unusual character used as a delimiter) the way you do when using an alternate delimiter in an address.

  Also, regarding the `c` command, it's worth knowing that including the new text on the same line as the `c\` is a GNU extension and not portable.

---

Putting all this together, you can either use the `s` command like so:

```
sed -i 's:"\.\./\.\./\.\./Plumed\.h":"/usr/local/include/Plumed.h":g' ../dist0.xvg
```

Or, if you want to be even more explicit, you can use an anchored regex and the `c`hange command to change the whole line only:

```
sed -i '\:^#include "\.\./\.\./\.\./Plumed\.h"$:c\#include "/usr/local/include/Plumed.h"' ../dist0.xvg
```

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me :

```
     sed -i 's#include "../../../Plumed.h"#include "/usr/local/include/Plumed.h"#g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use exclamation point if there is many slashes in the text:

```
sed -e 's!../../../Plumed.h!/usr/local/include/Plumed.h!'
```